# JSON Deserialization w/ Parse API IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, youtube, parse-platform

I've go some issues with Parse API and then short beginning tutorial;

Here's my code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Ovrride point for customization after application launch.

    [Parse setApplicationId:@"8cyxBir0KXluAqQCBqjT4loQy7GpcCCSqYlpqLfG"
                  clientKey:@"PVjBALJsToq5XRldBC0KHG0INQQdh4wE7xzWmfy1"];
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
    testObject[@"foo"] = @"bar";
    [testObject saveInBackground];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

And my error Message is:

> 2014-02-21 19:12:23.332 Youtuber[6590:3e07] JSON deserialization
>   failed. Error trace is: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Garbage at
>   end.) UserInfo=0x9a80360 {NSDebugDescription=Garbage at end.}
>   2014-02-21 19:12:23.333 Youtuber[6590:3e07] Error: (null) (Code: 0,
>   Version: 1.2.18) 2014-02-21 19:12:23.334 Youtuber[6590:390f]
>   runEventually command failed. Error:Error Domain=Parse Code=0 "The
>   operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 0.)"

I want to make an app for a Youtuber with Parse (Parse will gives a array with Video's name, description, And URL (Is this possible?, I don't know parse yet, is it's impossible, have you any tutorial or Code sample where I can retrieve all uploaded videos from a youtuber in a list view?)

Comment: I am getting the same error at my end. I am not able to figure out, What is the problem !!

Comment: Use Charles to see what is sent and received...

Comment: It's probably from their server, or their tutorial is outdated, i'll ask on their forum and hope an answer

Comment: Ooops, it says error, but object are sent ;)

Comment: You can track this on Parse's support forums here: https://parse.com/questions/error-json-deserialization-failed-runeventually-command-failed

Answer (score 0):

You should **import**  in your **".pch"** file instead of **AppDelegate.m**